# How can I filter an pandas dataframe with another Smaller pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have 2 Data frames the first looks like this

df1:

```
    MONEY    Value
0    EUR      850
1    USD      750
2    CLP        1
3    DCN        1
```

df2:

```
      Money
0      USD
1      USD
2      USD
3      USD
4      EGP
...    ...
25984  USD
25985  DCN
25986  USD
25987  CLP
25988  USD
```

I want to remove the "Money" values of df2 that are not present in df1. and add any column of the values of the "Value" column in df1

```
  Money    Value
0      USD      720
1      USD      720
2      USD      720
3      USD      720
...    ...
25984  USD      720
25985  DCN        1
25986  USD      720
25987  CLP        1
25000  USD      720
```

Comment: Something like `df2["Money"].map(df1.set_index("MONEY")["Value"]).dropna() `

Comment: It Kinda worked. But did
`df2['Value'] = df2["Money"].map(df1.set_index("MONEY")["Value"]).dropna()`
Can You explain it in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Step by step:**

1. 

```
df1.set_index("MONEY")["Value"]
```

This code transforms the column `MONEY` into the `Dataframe` index. Which results in:

```
    print(df1)

    MONEY
    EUR    850
    USD    150
    DCN      1
```

---

2. 

```
df2["Money"].map(df1.set_index("MONEY")["Value"])
```

This code maps the content of `df2` to `df1`. This returns the following:

```
    0    150.0
    1      NaN
    2    850.0
    3      NaN
```

---

3. Now we assign the previous column to a new column in `df2` called `Value`. Putting it all together:

```
df2["Value"] = df2["Money"].map(df1.set_index("MONEY")["Value"])
```

`df2` now looks like:

```
     Money  Value
    0   USD  150.0
    1   GBP    NaN
    2   EUR  850.0
    3   CLP    NaN
```

---

4. Only one thing is left to do: Delete any rows that have `NaN` value:

```
df2.dropna(inplace=True)
```

---

**Entire code sample:**

```
import pandas as pd

# Create df1
x_1 = ["EUR", 850], ["USD", 150], ["DCN", 1]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x_1, columns=["MONEY", "Value"])

# Create d2
x_2 = "USD", "GBP", "EUR", "CLP"
df2 = pd.DataFrame(x_2, columns=["Money"])

# Create new column in df2 called 'Value'
df2["Value"] = df2["Money"].map(df1.set_index("MONEY")["Value"])
# Drops any rows that have 'NaN' in column 'Value'
df2.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df2)
```

**Outputs:**

```
Money  Value
0   USD  150.0
2   EUR  850.0
```